# Ehcache RMI replication does not work on linux with tomcat but works fine on windows?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, ehcache, distributed-caching

we are have installed two instances of a server which is a web application say SampleWebApp on two systems on linux. We have configured ehcache to cache local data and also a default RMI replication to replicate changes done on Server1 to Server2. The replication works fine on Windows environment but it does not work on Linux environment. Even there is no error printed, it fails silently.

The configurations done in ehcache.xml file are below-

```
    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory              class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
    rmiUrls=//<ip>:50000/sampleReplicatedCache"
    propertySeparator="," />
    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory             class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"   properties="port=40000"/>
    <cache name="cmServerReplicatedCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" >
    <cacheEventListenerFactory       class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
    properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
    replicatePutsViaCopy=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,           replicateRemovals=false,   asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=5000"/>
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory      class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
    </cache>
```

There is no firewall installed which could block replication so firewall is not a reason why it is failing. 
Also checked if ports are opened. Allocated port 50000 is opened and Ehcache listens to this port. Problem is that if there is update in cache, this change is not getting replicated.

Any suggestions or clarifications on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Wonder!

Comment: This problem is solved. Forgot to post the answer. Issue was that I was using tokens in ehcache.xml but spring expression resolver (token replacement using ${}) is not supported in ehcache.xml file since the file does not come under spring application context. I replaced the tokens with actual values and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. Forgot to post the answer. Issue was that I was using tokens in ehcache.xml but spring expression resolver (token replacement using ${}) is not supported in ehcache.xml file since the file does not come under spring application context. I replaced the tokens with actual values and then it worked